# Is delegating code that may throw exception to functions considered good coding standard?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I'm refactoring some code and came across a large function with several input parameters. It checks whether the parameters are correct and throws exceptions if they're not:

```
public void fun(int param1, int param2) Throws Exception {
    if(check_param(param1)) {
         throw new Exception("param1 not okay");
    }
    // ... large chunk of code
}
```

I'd like to refactor the code, to move initial parameters checking into a separate function:

```
public void checkParams(int param1, int param2) Throws Exception {
    if(check_param(param1)) {
         throw new Exception("param1 not okay");
    }
}

public void fun(int param1, int param2) Throws Exception {
    checkParams(param1, param2);
    // ... large chunk of code
}
```

Note: the function *fun* no longer throws an exception directly. I'd like to let the exception flow through *fun* but I'm not sure if this is considered good style or is recommended? Try&catch-ing the exception seems redundant. What's the right way to let "internal" exception flow through? (just ignore?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> (just ignore?)

That is exactly right, and it is the whole point of the semantics of exceptions: signaling error at one point and handling it at a separate, possibly very distant point, where the same type of error can be handled uniformly regardless of the exact location on the code path where it was detected.

Precondition checking is a well-known and frequent use case for exceptions which flow through the caller method. Typically you will want to define a custom exception type, such as `ValidationException`, and have only one place in your codebase where you catch and handle it.

Comment: I come from non-exception C++ development, so the practical advice here is real helpful, thanks Marko!

Comment: Yes, compared to non-exception code, exceptions can save you a lot of boilerplate code. More importantly, the code is much more robust when the default behavior is breaking due to error---instead of silently ignoring it when it is signalled over the regular return value.

Answer (score 0):

There is no coding standard that says that this is good style ... or bad style.

You need to think of this in terms of what matters:

- Does it make the code easier to read?
- Does it make the code easier to maintain?
- Does it reduce code duplication ... significantly?

In the example you have given, I'd be inclined to say that it doesn't meet any of those criteria, and that this refactoring is probably a bad idea.  However, it is clear that this example is not "real code".

---

> Try & catching the exception seems redundant. What's the right way to let "internal" exception flow through? (just ignore?)

I don't know exactly what you are saying here.  But in the context of your example, catching the exception inside `fun` would be just plain wrong.  And catching it and ignoring it (anywhere) is even worse.

The whole point is that the exception needs to propagate to the caller (or beyond) and that it ultimately should be caught and properly dealt with.  (What "properly dealt with" means will depend on what the exception was, whether it can be anticipated, and what if anything can be done to recover.)

Catching and ignoring an exception is almost always wrong.  The only case where it is right is when you know exactly what it means, and have decided that it is *safe* and *correct* to ignore it.

Of course, declaring the "internal" class as throwing an exception is NOT ignoring it.

---

I hope that you are using `Exception` as just an example.

In fact, it is a very bad idea to throw `Exception`, `RuntimeException` or one of the other exception base classes.  You should always throw a more specific exception, to allow the caller to discriminate expected exceptions from unexpected ones.  If you throw `Exception` it is next to impossible to be distinguish an anticipated exception (e.g. the `Exception` that you throw) from an unanticipated one; e.g. a `NullPointerException` caused by some bug.

I also hope that you are NOT in the habit of declaring your "internal" methods as `public`.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. I'd say the production code does in fact meet some of the criteria you've mentioned hence the changes. *fun* is just the interface - I consider it a black box for outsiders and try to refactor it for easier maintenance. With that in mind I believe moving the checks and defining ValidationException is the right way (hence Marko's answer's acceptance).

Comment: @hauron - Like I said, it is to you (and your peers) to decide whether this refactoring is good or not.  But I'm not convinced that you should be considering a method as an interface.  The *natural* interface is the method signature and the javadoc comments.  Outsiders (i.e. programmers) shouldn't need to look at the `fun` method body at all ... if you have documented it sufficiently.  And when they do need to look at it (e.g. to track down a bug), then they *probably* need to see everything, not just the "interface" code.

Comment: I agree, in this scenario the *fun* method does in fact provide all the information within it's declaration - the fact that thrown exceptions are delegated to inner functions is irrelevant (and hidden) to the outsiders.

Answer (score 0):

*(Judgemental)*

A `checkParam` throwing an exception makes much sense. The error message has appearantly sufficient knowledge, and needs only to be formulated once. It is a kind of DRY (don't repeat yourself).

Even more important: error cases give rare control flow paths. Are hard to test, are seldom seen. Should steel little developer effort. So who checks that the exception (message) still makes sense. And having all those extra code and strings.

I even often iincline to unchecked exceptions like `IllegalArgumentException`, but `IOException` is a good second.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check for disparate exceptions as they bubble up the call stack then it's a neat idea to create exception classes like `Param1NotOKException` which extend the `java.lang.Exception` class.

Then you can add `throws Param1NotOKException` to the relevant functions. You then know exactly what is and isn't going to be thrown and the logic is checked at compile time.

Obviously this fine level of granularity could make things unwieldy so some half-way house between this idea and throwing and catching `java.lang.Exception` instances is probably what you ought to end up doing.